# Can the Tweepy cursor search query go through a list of words loaded from a file?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to make my bot be able to search for multiple keywords through the search API. So far I have:

```py
f = open('swear.txt', 'r')
search = f.read().splitlines()
f.close()

for x in search: #goes through each keyword
    print (x)

numberOfTweets = 5
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=search).items(numberOfTweets):
    tweet.retweet()
```

As seen, search holds the strings read in from a file but how do I make the search go through each string? Some sort of lambda function? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood right, you want to use every word (in this case "x") to search for them with the tweepy.Cursor? If so, your answer is pretty simple.

```
f = open('swear.txt', 'r')
search = f.read().splitlines()
f.close()

numberOfTweets = 5
for x in search: #goes through each keyword
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=x).items(numberOfTweets):
        tweet.retweet()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought about doing it this way, but I guess I had a question regarding what's actually happening.

Does it search twitter 5 times for the first word, then search twitter 5 times for the 2nd and on and on? If then, I could reach the rate limit before I get to the last word.

Comment: The `number_of_tweets` is just a limit how many tweets should be fetched, its one request, be it 1000 or 1 tweet.

Its gonna search for every word ONCE, and retweet it too.